# What do those functions other than __init__ do for the code?

Tags: python, class

```
class Cellphone:
  def __init__(self, manufact, model, price):
    self.__manufact = manufact
    self.__model = model
    self.__retail_price = price

  def set_manufact(self, manufact):
    self.__manufact = manufact

  def set_model(self, model):
    self.model = model

  def set_retail_price(self, price):
    self.__retail_price = price

  def get_manufact(self):
    return self.__manufact

  def get_model(self):
    return self.__model

  def get_retail_price(self):
    return self.__retail_price
```

I kind of understand __init__ is something you just have to have inside of a class However, the rest of the fucntions like def get_retail or really rest of the functions, I don't know what their purpose is..
I've read from other website about what __init__ does but I really can't seem to grasp the idea of it. I know how to use the __init__ but I don't know what it actually does. 
I'm sorry if my question is all over the place, it kind of resembles how I understand this whole class thing

Comment: They're referred to as getters/setters

Comment: I guess then my question becomes what does getters/setters do? and will the code run fine even without them? 
I don't see the point of using them

Comment: It looks like a **bad example** of applying Java (?) programming style to Python code. Dynamic languages allow cleaner way to achieve the same result, for example, `dataclasses`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make a instance of the class, then you're calling the init function

```
c = Cellphone(1,2,3)
```

Then you need to access those values later, so you'd get them

```
print(c.get_retail_price())
```

Then, let's say that the phone went on sale, you'd have to set the price

```
c.set_retail_price(2)
print(c.get_retail_price())
```

Answer (score 0):

To be as simple as possible, those functions are simply **setter** and **getter** **functions** for the class. There purpose is to either define the class members (in the case of the setter functions) or retrieve data from the class (in the case of the getter functions). Hence the use of "set" and "get" terminology.

We want these functions in general for OOP programming because our functions are the only way we can interact with other objects in a program, hence object oriented programming.

The init function is simply a **constructor**, and it automatically runs every time you create an object of the class. It's supposed to make it easier to define its class members.